# Rails simple access control

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, access-control

I am aware that several gems are made to handle authorization in Rails. But is it really worth it to use these gems for simple access controls ?

I only have a few "roles" in my application, and I feel that a powerful gem would be useless and even slow down the response time.

I have already implemented a solution, but then I took some security classes (:p) and I realized my model was wrong ("Allow by default, then restrict"  instead of "Deny by default, then allow").

Now how can I simply implement a "deny by default, allow on specific cases" ?

Basically I'd like to put at the very top of my ApplicationController

```
class ApplicationController < ApplicationController::Base
  before_filter :deny_access
```

And at the very top of my other controllers :

```
class some_controller < ApplicationController
  before_filter :allow_access_to_[entity/user]
```

These `allow_access_to_` before_filters should do something like `skip_before_filter`

```
def allow_access_to_[...]
  skip_before_filter(:deny_access) if condition
end
```

But this doesn't work, because these `allow_access` before filters are not evaluated before the `deny_access` before_filter

Any workaround, better solution for this custom implementation of access control ?

**EDIT**

- Many non-RESTful actions
- I need per-action access control
- `undefined method 'skip_before_filter' for #<MyController...` why ?
- My before_filters can get tricky

```rb
before_action :find_project, except: [:index, :new, :create]
before_action(except: [:show, :index, :new, :create]) do |c|
   c.restrict_access_to_manager(@project.manager)
end
```

Comment: Before filters are called in the order that they are listed. But you can use `prepend_before_filter` for `allow_access_to_` to add it to the front of the stack of before filters.

Comment: make a lightweight mixin module that has a method named `authorize` (or something).  Add this module at the ApplicationController level and invoke `authorize` as the `ApplicationController's` `before_filter`.   Have the default implementation of `authorize` deny everything.   In your sub-Controllers, override `authorize` to do the authorization you want.  Basically this is just a DIY form of a simple authorization gem.

Comment: I need per-action access control. So I can't just redefine an `authorize` method in the controllers. Or, I would have to check inside this method which action I'm calling.

Comment: Same issue you'd have with the generic filters approach though.   Something like `cancancan` addresses this, but then that's an external gem (reasonably lightweight, but still outside the scope of your question).  If however, you follow a basic CRUD pattern, just assign methods to each of the CRUD letters and only override when that you have something odd.  Then in `authorize` do something like `if :read, then ` type logic.  Again if a mix-in, most of the sub-Controller's code would barely see it.  This keeps you from testing each action but lets you vary pretty easily (same as `cancancan`).

Comment: With filter approch, I can do `prepend_before_action :allow_access_to_, only: [:action1, :action2]`

Comment: Ah, right.   Still, breaking down `authorize` in the mixin to be `authorize_read`, etc. would let you do the same thing re the `only:`/`except:` modifiers.  By putting `authorize_read`, `authorize_create`, etc.  in the ApplicationController, you'd probably get 90% of it.

Comment: Also, I'm a little worried this might be premature optimization.  You stated that you're worried an existing gem might slow the code down to use an existing gem.  Until that code shows itself to be a significant bottleneck, you may be just reinventing the wheel which is often slower/buggier than a stock solution.  If I were you, I'd do a quick experiment with a gem and make sure the performance savings are really worth it before implementing a DIY solution.

Comment: This isn't so much about performance, but rather I feel what I need to do is too simple for a gem. And concerning security, well I'm just dealing with authorize/deny so I'm not sure this is relevant.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71624/discussion-between-rdnewman-and-cyril-dd).

Comment: One thing I would say is to avoid defining authorization per controller and action, and instead by object and action. The former prevents you from authorizing something outside of a particular controller action.

Comment: Unfortunately my controllers are very RESTless, and it makes it difficult for a really object oriented-approach. For example, my ProjectController is only 1/5 RESTful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rolling your own implementation isn't necessarily bad as long as you're committed to it.

It won't get tested and maintained by the community so you must be willing to maintain it yourself in the long run, and if it compromises security you need to be really sure of what you're doing and take extra care. If you have that covered and the existing alternatives don't really fit your needs, making your own isn't such a bad idea. And generally it's an incredibly good learning experience.

I rolled my own with [ActionAccess](https://github.com/matiasgagliano/action_access) and I couldn't be happier with the results.

- **Locked by default** aproach:

  ```
  class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    lock_access

    # ...
  end
  ```
- **Per-action** access control:

  ```
  class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
    let :admins, :all
    let :editors, [:index, :show, :edit, :update]
    let :all, [:index, :show]

    def index
      # ...
    end

    # ...
  end
  ```
- Really **lighweight** implementation.

I encourage you not to use it but to check out the source code, it has a fare share of comments and should be a good source of inspiration. [ControllerAdditions](https://github.com/matiasgagliano/action_access/blob/master/lib/action_access/controller_additions.rb) might be a good place to start.

ActionAccess follows a different approach internally, but you can refactor your answer to mimic it's API with something like this:

```
module AccessControl
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    before_filter :lock_access
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def lock_access
      unless @authorized
        # Redirect user...
      end
    end

    def allow_manager_to(actions = [])
      prepend_before_action only: actions do
        @authorized = true if current_user_is_a_manager?
      end
    end
  end
end

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include AccessControl  # Locked by default

  # ...
end

class ProjectController < ApplicationController
  allow_managers_to [:edit, :update]  # Per-action access control

  # ...
end
```

Take this example as pseudo-code, I haven't tested it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for adding this answer. I like your syntax/names, it looks clean, and I'll definitely have a look at your gem to get some inspiration !

Answer (score 3):

I would really advise using a proper battle tested gem for authentication & authorisation instead of rolling your own. These gems have enormous test suites and aren't really all that hard to setup.

I've recently implemented an action based authorization using roles with [Pundit](https://github.com/elabs/pundit) & [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)

Devise is changeable as long as the gem you are using provides a `current_user` method if you don't want to further configure pundit.

```
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include Pundit

  rescue_from Pundit::NotAuthorizedError, with: :rescue_unauthorized

  # Lock actions untill authorization is performed
  before_action :authorize_user

  # Fallback when not authorized
  def rescue_unauthorized(exception)
    policy_name = exception.policy.class.to_s.underscore
    flash[:notice] = t(
      "#{policy_name}.#{exception.query}",
      scope: "pundit",
      default: :default
    )
    redirect_to(request.referrer || root_path)
  end
end

# app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :roles, through: :memberships

  def authorized?(action)
    claim = String(action)
    roles.pluck(:claim).any? { |role_claim| role_claim == claim }
  end
end

# app/policies/user_policy.rb => maps to user_controller#actions
class UserPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  class Scope < Scope
    attr_reader :user, :scope

    # user is automagically set to current_user
    def initialize(user, scope)
      @user = user
      @scope = scope
    end

    def resolve
      scope.all
    end
  end

  def index?
    # If user has a role which has the claim :view_users
    # Allow this user to use the user#index action
    @user.authorized? :view_users 
  end

  def new?
    @user.authorized? :new_users
  end

  def edit?
    @user.authorized? :edit_users
  end

  def create?
    new?
  end

  def update?
    edit?
  end

  def destroy?
    @user.authorized? :destroy_users
  end
end
```

Long story short:

If you configure pundit to force authorization on each request which is described in detail on the github page, the controller evaluates a policy based on the used controller.

```
UserController -> UserPolicy
```

Actions get defined with a question mark, even non restful routes.

```
def index?
  # authorization is done inside the method.
  # true = authorization succes
  # false = authorization failure
end
```

This is my solution to action based authorization hope it helps you out.

Optimisations & feedback are welcome !

Comment: My users "roles" come from a LDAP, and I manually rebuild a cache of user groups. Not sure I could interface this easily with gems. But I'll give a try to some gems. And yes I also use Devise.

Comment: I don't think the problem is with the gems you could use. If you can make the `current_user` aware of the `roles` he has with corresponding allowed actions you can easily build your own authorization system with pundit.

Pundit just expects a true or false to evaluate if the person is authorized or not.

Comment: Devise is for authentication, not authorization. Pundit is so simple you can roll your own with little effort, it really doesn’t give you much (but it’s design is, in general, good—much better than CanCan(Can)).

Answer (score 0):

EDIT : Outdated answer, I have a friendlier implementation that involves using an `access_control` block

Going with evanbikes suggestion, for now I'll be using prepend_before action. I find it quite simple & flexible, but if I ever realize it's not good enough I will try other things.

Also if you find security issues/other problems with the solution below, please comment and/or downvote. I don't like leaving bad examples in SO.

```
class ApplicationController < ApplicationController::Base
  include AccessControl
  before_filter :access_denied
  ...
```

My Access Control module

```
module AccessControl
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do
    def access_denied(message: nil)
        unless @authorized
            flash.alert = 'Unauthorized access'
            flash.info = "Authorized entities : #{@authorized_entities.join(', '}" if @authorized_entities
            render 'static_pages/home', :status => :unauthorized
            end
        end

        def allow_access_to_managers
            (@authorized_entities ||= []) << "Project managers"
            @authorized = true if manager_logged_in?
        end
        ...
```

How I use the AC in controllers :

```
class ProjectController < ApplicationController
  # In reverse because `prepend_` is LIFO
  prepend_before_action(except: [:show, :index, :new, :create]) do |c|
    c.allow_access_to_manager(@manager.administrateur)
  end
  prepend_before_action :find_manager, except: [:index, :new, :create]
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't like my previous solution using `prepend_before_action`, here is a nice implementation using ActionController callbacks

```
module AccessControl
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  class UnauthorizedException < Exception
  end

  class_methods do
    define_method :access_control do |*names, &blk|
      _insert_callbacks(names, blk) do |name, options|
        set_callback(:access_control, :before, name, options)
      end
    end
  end

  included do

    define_callbacks :access_control

    before_action :deny_by_default
    around_action :perform_if_access_granted

    def perform_if_access_granted
      run_callbacks :access_control do
        if @access_denied and not @access_authorized
          @request_authentication = true unless user_signed_in?
          render(
            file: File.join(Rails.root, 'app/views/errors/403.html'),
            status: 403,
            layout: 'error')
        else
          yield
        end
      end
    end

    def deny_by_default
      @access_denied ||= true
    end

    def allow_access
      @access_authorized = true
    end
  end
end
```

Then you can add your own `allow_access_to_x` methods (for example in the same AccessControl concern) :

```
def allow_access_to_participants_of(project)
  return unless user_signed_in?
  allow_access if current_user.in?(project.executants)
end
```

Use it in your controllers the following way (don't forget to include AccessControl in your `ApplicationController`

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  access_control(only: [:show, :edit, :update]) do
    set_project
    allow_access_to_participants_of(@project)
    allow_access_to_project_managers
  end

  def index; ...; end;
  def show; ...; end;
  def edit; ...; end;
  def update; ...; end;

  def set_project
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
  end
end
```